# nginx + pam authentification with different user groups to different locations

Tags: authentication, nginx, pam

I'm trying to configure nginx in the following way. I've got several services running, and want to give access to them by setting up different nginx locations. I also want to manage user authentification using PAM, and allow users to access locations based on their group. So I've created th following config:

```
server {
   listen 80;

   location /service1/ {
       auth_pam "Accessing service1";
       auth_pam_service_name "service1";

       rewrite ^/service1/(.*)$ /$1 break;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
       proxy_redirect http://localhost:1234/ $scheme://$host/service1/;
   }

   location /service2/ {
       auth_pam "Accessing service2";
       auth_pam_service_name "service2";

       rewrite ^/service2/(.*)$ /$1 break;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:5678;
       proxy_redirect http://localhost:5678/ $scheme://$host/service2/;
   }
}
```

I also created following files, with the following contents:

/etc/pam.d/service1:

```
auth required pam_listfile.so onerr=fail item=group sense=allow file=/etc/service1.group.allow
@include common-auth
```

/etc/pam.d/service2:

```
auth required pam_listfile.so onerr=fail item=group sense=allow file=/etc/service2.group.allow
@include common-auth
```

/etc/service1.group.allow:

```
service1-group
```

/etc/service2.group.allow:

```
service2-group
```

Everything works, only users from service1-group can access /service1/, only users from service2-group can access /service2/. Now consider user1 is a member of both service1-group and service2-group. I try to access /service1/, enter user1 and his password, successfully access /service1/. Now I navigate to /service2/, and I need to login again, again as user1. Is it possible to somehow save user under which I authorized and show the login window only if that user doesn't have permission to access the location. I.e., if user1 is memeber of service1-group and service2-group, I can access /service1/, login here, and then navigate to /service2/ without new login, but if user1 is a member of service1-group, and not a memeber of service2-group, I can access /service1/, login here, and when trying to navigate to /service2/, login window shoul appear (as only service2-group members are allowed, and currently logged user1 is not)?